# Android analog time picker for iOS?

Tags: ios, datetimepicker, timepicker

I want to create an analog time picker similar to one you can find in Android, how to do it in iOS, someone can give me an idea?

[image: android analog time picker]

Thanks

Comment: Any particular reason for that? It will just feel wrong when using it. The regular iOS user expects the iOS date/time picker, not some custom-made android-style thingy which will look and feel out-of-place in iOS.

Comment: I tend to agree with @luk2302. It's possible to create such a control, but that doesn't mean that you should.

Comment: Well, I tend to agree with both of you, but that's what my clients wants.. what can I say? he pays the bill :) I suggested him to use UIDatePicker but he is an Android user and this is what he wants..

Comment: Sound like a perfect example to use some A/B testing and showing him that the iOS user will get stuck on the screen and (maybe a tiny bit) frustrated.

Comment: @YossiTsafar can you give me link of such sample code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I created a fully functioning analog clock as a demo of the spring animation feature added to iOS. It's on Github at https://github.com/DuncanMC/ClockAnimation. You could start from that. You'd need to rip out the time-telling part, and add a gesture recognizer for setting the amount of time. There is another project on Github that creates a one-finger rotation gesture recognizer. That would be a good option for setting the timer: https://github.com/kirbyt/KTOneFingerRotationGestureRecognizer